# Dynamically loading an external JavaScript response

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm using this code to include dynamically js file in run-time:

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src="js-debug/"+record.getId()+".js";

script.onload = function() {
      inizializeComponent();
}
```

For every node of menu, I include a different js file.

Now I need to intercept the event triggered when the page does not exist to show a messagebox!

How can I get it?

Comment: in script.src there is the path of js file that i dynamically include! for example, when user click on the first node of menu:          script.src = js-debug/1.js but if this page not exist i need to intrercept this event to show an error messagebox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `script.onerror = function () { ...`.

Comment: thanks! it's works fine on Mozilla but not good for internet explorer! how can i use script.onerror also in Internet Explorer?

Comment: ok! now it works also in IE9 - i need of this <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">